# Proper DNS resolution order in resolve.conf

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, dnscrypt, pihole

If I’m running something like NordVPN and force the order of DNS resolvers to be the IP of my gateway followed by the DNS of the VPN, will pi-hole still function as intended (technically , Dnsmasq). In NordVPN, you can select a “custom DNS”. If I add my gateway IP there, NordVPN automatically adds the IP to the end of resolv.conf, whereas my current configuration involves forcing it to the front of the list.

So, what is the proper configuration?

Comment: What OS is in play and can you make resolv.conf immutable?

Comment: Mojave. I could make it immutable, but not sure what the repercussions could be. I'm not super experienced with networks. It's annoying to have to force the setting every time I turn my VPN on, but my real concern is if there's even a point to what Im doing. I'm not convinced that my VPN and Dnsmasq are working symbiotically.